# MySQL - update rows if field records are not identical

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables in my database.
For example t1 and t2.
Script updates t1 records every one minute.
I need to copy t1 records (rows) to t2 if it doesn't exists or data in fields are not identical.

Here is steps i need to perform after script updates t1 table:

1. Database compares t1 records to t2
2. If some t1 records are not identical/missing inserts/updates it in t2.

This is like livescore. I need only update/insert/delete effected rows and not whole table.

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Step 1 seems redundant

Answer (score 0):

create two trigger for different action

for update action

```
create trigger update_t1
after update  on t1 for each row
begin

select count(*) from t2 where id=New.id  into @num;

if @num=0 then
/*insert into t2; */

else
/*update t2 */
end if;
end;
```

for insert action

```
create trigger insert_t1
    after insert  on t1 for each row
    begin

    /*insert into t2; */

    end;
```